# How do I make an integer to hex converter with python?

Tags: python, hex

I am currently trying to make an int to hex converter in python. I have tried running my code, but it
kept on giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Saumya\Documents\Coding\Python\hex.py", line 2, in <module>
    hex(num1)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Here is my code:

```
num1 = input("Enter a Number to Convert to Hex:")
hex(num1)
```

please give me an answer asap.

Comment: First of all you actually have to convert it to an int...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` returns a string. You must cast it to an integer:

```
hex(int(num1))
```